# Why is it impossible that an investor buys only securities in levered firm?

Tags: equities, leverage

On page 5 of this [slide deck](https://gess.uni-mannheim.de/fileadmin/user_upload/19_Capital_Structure_MA.pdf), it says that if the value of levered firm is smaller than the unlevered one, then investor buys only securities in levered firms (which is understandable) and hence value of levered firm can only be larger or equal to unleveraged one.

This would mean that it is impossible for the investors to buy only securities in levered firm. Why is it so?

Comment: You wrote "This would mean that it is impossible for the investors to buy only securities in levered firm.". I do not understand this statement, can you expand on it? The first paragraph I understood.

Comment: if the value of levered firm is smaller than the unlevered one => investor buys only securities in levered firms. The slide then says that value of levered firm can only be larger or equal to unleveraged one, which means that in the slide, it is taken as given that it is impossible for the investors to buy only securities in levered firm..

Comment: We are trying to find an equilibrium, where investors are indifferent between L and U, some will buy L and some will buy U. (1) Assume L<U then nobody buy U, so **not an equilibrium** (conclusion: L>=U) (2) Assume L>U then nobody buys L, again **not an equilibrium** (we conclude that L<=U) (3) From the two previous conclusions we must have ((L>=U) and (L<=U)) therefore we conclude that $L=U$ is **the only situation that is compatible with equilibrium**.